# How to display several messages on screen with Watson Conversation

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I'm working on a chatbot with Watson technology and more precisely with conversation service. It's my first application on Bluemix and with javascript and i have an issue with the display message of my chatbot. I explain: currently I have this code :

`var text = response.output.text[0]; // only display first value`

And my function `displayMessage`

```
function displayMessage(text, user) {

        var chat = document.getElementById('chatBox');
        var bubble = document.createElement('div');
        bubble.className = 'message';  // Wrap the text first in a message class for common formatting

        // Set chat bubble color and position based on the user parameter
        if (user === watson) {
            bubble.innerHTML = "<div class='bot'>" + text + "</div>";
        } else {
            bubble.innerHTML = "<div class='user'>" + text + "</div>";
        }

        chat.appendChild(bubble);
        chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;  // Move chat down to the last message displayed
        document.getElementById('chatMessage').focus();

        return null;
}
```

The problem currently is that the function only displays my first value, but in some cases I have to display n message (n is always < 10)
So I think about the creation of an array[10] to store my message with `while (array[i] != undefined)`. But my error is with the display in the function displayMessage - I don't know how display several messages. I tried this:

```
bubble.innerHTML = "<div class='bot'>" + tab[tmp] + "</div>";
```

and a loop while same as in my declaration but it didn't work.

Someone could help me?

Thank you

Edit n°1 
To inform you this is my first loop while creating my tab :

```
var tab = new Array(response.output.text[0]); // array with my different text
        var tmp = 1;
        while(response.output.text[tmp] != undefined){
            tab[tmp] = response.output.text[tmp]; // only display first value if second is null
            tmp = tmp + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier approach. JS allows you to 'join' all the elements in an array:

```
text = response.output.text.join(" ");
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: That's the approach I took although I think join will only work for an array so I've used `Array.isArray(text)` to check first. It looks like @cpradeil is working with the example project I forked by coincidence, so here's a link to my updates in the `displayMessage` function... https://github.com/jthub/watson-murder-mystery/blob/9106438bec68c3c90504610ce4017b8e3e6b6d75/public/src/bot.js#L170

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, a litlle savage but it's working currently so if someone have a better solution i will take it.

I create an array like in my post then when i instatiate my bubber.innerHTML i do

```
bubble.innerHTML = "<div class='bot'>" + tab[0] + tab[1]+ tab[2] + tab[3] + tab[4] +tab[5] + tab[6]+ tab[7]+ "</div>";
```

Because my array is always taller than 7